# how to prevent manual changes (that are not written by the script) on a sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google sheet where I need data to be entered on it **only by script** and I need to protect it from **manual adjustment** by protecting the rows already filled by script, the case is we are a team and a script logs all the changes every team member does in a row on a separate sheet (ChangeLog).

The Question: How can I use script to protect a row once data is logged in it by another script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fixing a code that prevents data already entered on cells from being modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48041058/fixing-a-code-that-prevents-data-already-entered-on-cells-from-being-modified)

Answer (score 0):

We can use range protection and installable triggers created by people with edit access to the protected ranges to edit them while preventing the manual changes made by non-editors. For further details see [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)