# Fixing a code that prevents data already entered on cells from being modified

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This code prevents data from being modified after it is entered for the first time by comparing it to a Helper sheet and returning the data already stored in the helper sheet if a change is done on an already filled cell.

The question: the issue with this code is if you select multiple cells and clicked delete on your keyboard all the cells are deleted and the code wont work as it should, how can I solve this issue ?

The code:

```
function onEdit() {


  var masterSheetName = "sheet1" // sheet where the cells are protected from updates
  var helperSheetName = "Helper" // sheet where the values are copied for later checking
  var firstDataRow = 1; // only take into account edits on or below this row
  var firstDataColumn = 1; // only take into account edits on or to the right of this column

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var masterSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if (masterSheet.getName() != masterSheetName) return;

  var masterCell = masterSheet.getActiveCell();
  if (masterCell.getRow() < firstDataRow || masterCell.getColumn() < firstDataColumn) return;

  var helperSheet = ss.getSheetByName(helperSheetName);
  var helperCell = helperSheet.getRange(masterCell.getA1Notation());
  var newValue = masterCell.getValue();
  var oldValue = helperCell.getValue();

  if (oldValue == "") {
    helperCell.setValue(newValue);
  } else {
    masterCell.setValue(oldValue);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the question? Solve which issue? What are you expecting?

Comment: The issue is that the code does not work properly protecting the sheet from being modified, IF the user selects multiple cells and deletes them, how can i modify this script to protect the sheet from multi-select and delete or to make it check all the cells, dynamically not just the active cell ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works for you. It checks the size of the selected range and if it is greater than one cell it resets the range to the helper sheet values.

```
function onEdit() {
  var masterSheetName = "sheet1" // sheet where the cells are protected from updates
  var helperSheetName = "Helper" // sheet where the values are copied for later checking
  var firstDataRow = 1; // only take into account edits on or below this row
  var firstDataColumn = 1; // only take into account edits on or to the right of this column

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var masterSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if (masterSheet.getName() != masterSheetName) return;
    var masterCell = masterSheet.getActiveCell();
  if (masterCell.getRow() < firstDataRow || masterCell.getColumn() < firstDataColumn) return;
    var helperSheet = ss.getSheetByName(helperSheetName);
    var helperCell = helperSheet.getRange(masterCell.getA1Notation());
    var newValue = masterCell.getValue();
    var oldValue = helperCell.getValue();

  if (oldValue == "") {
      helperCell.setValue(newValue);
  } else {
      masterCell.setValue(oldValue);
  }
  var test=masterSheet.getActiveRange().getA1Notation()//get the selected range
  var testsize=masterSheet.getActiveRange().getValues()//create an array of selected values
  var size=testsize.length// array length
  if(size>1){//if length of selected range is greater than one cell
      Browser.msgBox("Select only one cell")
      var helperSheet1 = ss.getSheetByName(helperSheetName).getRange(test).getValues();
      var masterSheet1= ss.getSheetByName(masterSheetName).getRange(test).getValues();
      var masterSheet1= ss.getSheetByName(masterSheetName).getRange(test).setValues(helperSheet1);//reset range
    } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like to me you need to add an event listener to listen explicitly for the instance where multiple cells are selected and the delete key is pressed, then just add a callback to repopulate data set from the helper sheet

Answer (score 0):

Range Protection is a built-in feature to prevent that data entered be modified, use it instead of overwriting old values. You could use [protect()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#protect) to change the protection settings.

Regarding the OP code, it misses the edit event object and instead uses "getActiveSomething" methods. This is inefficient. By the other hand, the code use [getActiveCell](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getactivecell) which returns the active cell, while the range property of the edit event object returns the range being edited.

If for any reason Range Protection can't be used, the following is an alternative to the OP code that works for edits of several cells at once, like pasting a value to several cells, or deleting several cells.

NOTE 1: Some validations on the OP code are omitted to simplify the code.

NOTE 2: It doesn't consider the case of pasting a range that include some empty cells while other cells aren't.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // If the edit is made on an invalid sheet, exit.
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName() != 'Sheet1') return;

  // Count the number of cells being edited
  var cellsNumber = [].concat.apply([],e.range.getValues()).length; 

  if(cellsNumber == 1 ){
    var helper = e.source.getSheetByName('Helper').getRange(e.range.getA1Notation());
    if(e.range.getValue() != ''){
      helper.setValue(e.value);
    } else {
      e.range.setValue(helper.getValue());
    }
  } else {
    var helper = e.source.getSheetByName('Helper').getRange(e.range.getA1Notation());

    // Count the number of characters on the edited range
    var charsNumber = [].concat.apply([],e.range.getValues()).join('').length;

    if(charsNumber > 0) {

      helper.setValues(e.range.getValues());
    } else {
      e.range.setValues(helper.getValues());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am getting this TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 93, file "Code")  on this line: if(e.range.getSheet().getName() != 'Sheet1') return;

Comment: well it worked but i am using 3 onEdit functions and i am unable to use that with the other 2, do you have any idea how to use it with other onEdit functions ?

Comment: @MostafaAbusamra If we use the same function name, any new instance  overwrites the previous definition. Assign different names to each one then you could call each from one "master" onEdit function.

Comment: well i have 3 onEdit functions i named them onEdit1(), onEdit2(), onEdit3(e) under a main function onEdit(e), but it did not work, it was working with 2 functions under it but when i add the 3rd one the last } stays red, and the function gives the Error on range as i 1st commented here

Comment: @MostafaAbusamra Please post a new question including a [mcve]